# missing ) after argument list onclick in generated HTML Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am generating an anchor link in my ruby on rails application. However when I perform an onclick operation, I get the following error:

```
missing ) after argument list onclick
```

The generated HTML is: `<a href='javascript:;', id="user_0", onclick = "myfunction(14,0,haris@email.com)" > Newcheckout </a>`

In my views in my ruby file I have written:

```
<a href='javascript:;', id="<%= 'user_' + i.to_s %>", onclick = "<%=  "myfunction(#{book.isbn},#{i},#{current_email_user})"%>" > Newcheckout </a>
```

As far I can see all my quotes are closed properly and brackets have been closed correctly as well.

Comment: haris@email.com is a string, thus should be closed -> 'haris@email.com'

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the string you are passing into `myfunction` in single quotes.

```
onclick = "myfunction(14,0,'haris@email.com')"
```

Comment: If I escape the variable in Ruby: onclick = '<%=  "myfunction(#{book.isbn},#{i},\"#{current_email_user}\")"%>'

The generated HTML is: 'myfunction(14,0,&quot;haris@email.com&quot;)'

I do not want &quot to come

Comment: I put .html_safe at the end and it worked now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might also be able to use `\'`. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#String_literals